# Proper diagonal Y axes for seaborn PairPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to use seaborn `pairplot` for some visualizations and I need to have proper diagonal Y axes (visible!) with no normalization at all (just counts) or the density normalization (sum of bin values = 1).
What is the better way to do it?

It is how I am trying to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.normal(0,2,[1000,3])

sss = sns.pairplot(pd.DataFrame(data),corner=True)
sss.axes[0][0].yaxis.tick_right()
sss.axes[0][0].get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
sss.axes[0][0].axis('on')
sss.axes[0][0].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
sss.axes[0][0].set_ylabel('Counts')
```

It gives me the following figure:

[image]

Evidently, I have the wrong normalization here (it is normalized on the maximum value, probably) and the y axis line itself is missing.

Comment: I believe the normalization is so as the total area of the histogram is `1`.

Comment: @QuangHoang probably you are right, but I'm looking for another normalization as I said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the y-axes on each row are shared, and the y-axis of the diagonal plot is essentially meaningless.

If you want to plot something there and preserve the scale of the data you are trying to plot, then you should "break" the shared axes somehow. The easiest way I can think of is to create a new axes at the same position using `twinx()`.

Of course, for this you need to be using `PairGrid()` instead of `pairplot()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def my_hist(x, label, color):
    ax0 = plt.gca()
    ax = ax0.twinx()
    
    sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True, top=True, right=False)
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
    
    ax.hist(x, label=label, color=color)

data = np.random.normal(0,2,[1000,3])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

g = sns.PairGrid(df,corner=True)
g.map_diag(my_hist)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)
```

[image]

Comment: You can turn off the diagonal y axis sharing in `pairplot` with `grid_kws=dict(diag_sharey=False)`. (I also think that's unrelated to the question of normalization?) The rest of the answer is very good for showing how to put a y axis for the marginal plots on the right, but you could also do it post-hoc by accessing the `PairGrid.diag_axes` attribute.